# Swagger codegen - api and model

Tags: rest, swagger, code-generation, swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

So this is codegen101 for me and I have been trying to use swagger plugin and keep getting error. Is it a known issue, I have tried serval versions for the plugin thinking it might be a known issue in one of them but no success at all.It should be pretty straight forward exercise. I am not sure what I am missing. Can someone point out please

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.18</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/service-api.yaml</inputSpec>
              <language>java</language>
              <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/</output>
              <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
              <apiPackage>com.openapi101.api</apiPackage>
              <modelPackage>com.openapi101.models</modelPackage>
              <configOptions>
                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
              </configOptions>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

error

```
[ERROR]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate model 'Book'
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.DefaultGenerator.generateModels (DefaultGenerator.java:451)
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.DefaultGenerator.generate (DefaultGenerator.java:779)
    at io.swagger.codegen.v3.maven.plugin.CodeGenMojo.execute (CodeGenMojo.java:547)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: com.github.jknack.handlebars.HandlebarsException: /handlebars/JavaSpring/pojo.mustache:2:6: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public boolean java.util.Collections$EmptyMap.isEmpty() accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @4bc33720
    /handlebars/JavaSpring/pojo.mustache:2:6
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible (AccessibleObject.java:357)
```

Edit : used the new version - 3.0.27 . Still did not work

here is the yaml file

```
openapi: 3.0.0
 
info:
  version: 0.0.1
  title: Library Service
  description: The library service
 
tags:
  - name: "Library"
 
 
paths:
 
  /library/books:
    get:
      summary: This is summary
      tags:
        - "Library"
      description: This is a description
      operationId: getAllBooksInLibrary
      responses:
        "200":
          description: This means its ok
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Book'
 
components:
 
  schemas:
 
    Book:
      description: This is the book model
      type: object
      properties:
        name:
          description: The name of book
          type: string
        bookAuthor:
          description: name of author
          type: string
```

Comment: Try the latest version, 3.0.27. If it still doesn't work, can you please post the `Book` schema from your OpenAPI YAML file?

Comment: Book Schema added above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. The solution is to simply use Java 8 to run it. This allowed me to run the generation without problems